# Python: Find a word in a 2d list and return the intersection that is the row index and column index of that word in a list

Tags: python-3.x

> Write a function named find_word_horizontal that accepts a
>   2-dimensional list of characters (like a crossword puzzle) and a
>   string (word) as input arguments. This function searches the rows of
>   the 2d list to find a match for the word.  If a match is found, this
>   functions returns a list containing row index and column index of the
>   start of the match,  otherwise it returns the value None (no
>   quotations).

**NOTE: I apologize for posting a long post here. I'm very sorry but without posting proper question it was impossible for me to ask for help.**

```
For example if the function is called as shown below:
> 
> crosswords=[['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','c','a','t'],['t','e','t','k']]
> word='cat'
> 
> find_word_horizontal(crosswords,word)
> 
> then your function should return [2,1]
> 
> Notice that the 2d input list represents a 2d crossword and the
> starting index of the horizontal word 'cat' is [2,1]
Note: In case of multiple matches only return the match with lower row index. If you find two matches in the same row 
then return the match with lower column index
```

I have written this code. Probably this may not be the best code but:

```
def find_word_horizontal (crosswords, word):
    list = []
    output_list = []
    row_index = -1
    column_index = 0
    list = word.split()
    for sublist in crosswords:
        if (sublist[1:] == list[:] or sublist[0:-1] == list[:]):
            column_index += 1
        row_index += 1
    output_list.append(row_index)
    output_list.append(column_index)
    return (output_list)

#Main Program
crosswords = [['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','c','a','t'],['t','e','t','k']]
word = 'cat'
result = find_word_horizontal(crosswords,word)
print (result)
```

What I'm doing here is first converting the word (i.e "cat") into a list. Second I have sliced the `sublist` (i.e a list within 2d list) to check for the three letter word "`cat`". I know I have kind of hard coded this but I couldn't find any other way. Tops, the question demands it to be in that way.

This is what I am getting in the output:

```
[3, 0]
```

Why isn't the if statement updating the value of column_index? Is there an issue with the slice order or what? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can a word extend across multiple rows, so the first three letters are in one list and the last two are in the next? If not, an easy approach might be to just join each row together and search the whole string rather comparing character by character. I can write up an answer later if you think this would work.

Comment: Sure> Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try it out, let me know how if works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps, I left some prints in so you could see what's going on:

```
def find_word_horizontal (crosswords, word):
    for row_index, row in enumerate(crosswords):
        print('input: ', row_index, row)
        row_string = ''.join(row)
        print('joined row: ', row_string)
        column_index = row_string.find(word)
        if(column_index > -1):
            return [row_index, column_index]

find_word_horizontal(crosswords, word)
```

Output:

```
input:  0 ['s', 'd', 'o', 'g']
joined row:  sdog
input:  1 ['c', 'u', 'c', 'm']
joined row:  cucm
input:  2 ['a', 'c', 'a', 't']
joined row:  acat
Out[5]: [2, 1]
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

`word.split()` doesn't split a word into an list of characters, but `list(word)` does. Then there was a slight logic flaw in getting the indexes but `enumerate` in a loop is useful here.

```
def find_word_horizontal (crosswords, word):
    input_list = list(word)
    output_list = []
    row_index = -1
    column_index = 0
    for outer_index, sublist in enumerate(crosswords):
        for inner_index in xrange(0,(len(sublist)-len(input_list)+1)):
            if sublist[inner_index:inner_index+len(input_list)]==input_list:
                return [outer_index,inner_index]
```

Its also probably not a good idea to name variables "list".

Comment: The above code just works for three letter words. This is the error I get when I run it. 
#Your function return is NOT correct but your printed output is correct.
#For example when your function is called as shown below:
#find_word_horizontal([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], 'cd')
#Your function returns:
#None
#The returned variable type from your function is: NoneType
#Instructor's function returns:
[1, 0]
#The returned variable type from instructor's function is: list

Comment: Also how do you traverse column elements for finding the match?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve it:

```
def find_word_horizontal(crossword,word):
    myindex = []
    for element in crossword :
        row = ''.join(element)
        if word in row :
            myindex.append(crossword.index(element))
            myindex.append(row.index(word))
    return myindex
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```py
def find_word_horizontal(crossword,word):  
    global row_index  
    number_of_rows=len(crossword)  
    number_of_columns=len(crossword[0])  
    row_items_list=[]  
    final_output=[]  
    for i in range(0,number_of_rows):  
        row_items=""  
        for j in range(0,number_of_columns):  
            row_items+=crossword[i][j]  
        row_items_list.append(row_items)  
    for i in row_items_list:  
        if word in i:  
            row_index=row_items_list.index(i)  
            for k in range(0,number_of_columns):  
                if(word[0]==crossword[row_index][k]):  
                    column_index=k  
                    final_output.append(row_index)  
                    final_output.append(column_index)  
                    return final_output  
                    break  
        else:  
            continue  

crosswords=[['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','c','a','t'],['t','e','t','k']]  
word='car'  
print(find_word_horizontal(crosswords,word))
```

Answer (score 0):

this is ok but if you find bug pls tell me. Thanks

```
def find_word_horizontal(a_list, w):
address = list()
for row in a_list:
    chek = ""
    for char in row:
        chek = chek + char
    #print(chek)
    if w in chek:
        address.append(a_list.index(row))
        address.append(chek.find(w))
        break
return address
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.